# Change the code c#

Tags: c#

I have some similar code used for displaying calculations that is repeated in all my calculate methods. How I can take this common code in one method and just pass the operator to it?

Common code:

```
       double lhs = double.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
       double rhs = double.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);

       // Do some calculation which sets 'outcome'
       // Set 'sign' equal to the string value of the operator

       expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + sign + rhsOperand.Text;
       result.Text = outcome.ToString();
```

Here's an example of how I'm currently calling different methods depending on the operation the user chose:

```
    private void calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (addition.Checked)
             additionValues();

         if (subtraction.Checked)
             subtractValues();

         if (multiplication.Checked)
             multiplicationValues();

         if (division.Checked)
             divisionValues();

         if (remainder.Checked)
             remainderValues();
    }
```

And here's an example of the calculation methods, which all share a common pattern. How can I make a single method that I could pass an operation to, and have it take care of multiple calculations depending on the operator I passed to it?

```
    private void subtractValues()
    {
        try
        {
            int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
            int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
            int outcome;
            outcome = lhs - rhs;
            expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + "-" + rhsOperand.Text;
            result.Text = outcome.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }


    }
    private void additionValues()
    {
        try
        {
            int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
            int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
            int outcome;
            outcome = lhs + rhs;
            expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + "+" + rhsOperand.Text;
            result.Text = outcome.ToString();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void multiplicationValues()
    {
        try
        {
            int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
            int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
            int outcome;
            outcome = lhs * rhs;
            expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + "*" + rhsOperand.Text;
            result.Text = outcome.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }
    private void divisionValues()
    {
        try
        {
            int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
            int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
            int outcome;
            outcome = lhs / rhs;
            expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + "/" + rhsOperand.Text;
            result.Text = outcome.ToString();
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }

    }
    private void remainderValues()
    {
        try
        {
            int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
            int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
            int outcome;
            outcome = lhs % rhs;
            expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + "%" + rhsOperand.Text;
            result.Text = outcome.ToString();
        }
        catch (DivideByZeroException e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void quit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "one method to all Values"?

Comment: double lhs = double.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
       double rhs = double.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
       expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + sign + rhsOperand.Text;
       result.Text = outcome.ToString();
This part is in all methods. I want to make one method and call them then I need it.

Comment: Well, why don't you put that part in its own method?

Comment: belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void MultiMethod(string sign)
{
    double lhs = double.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
    double rhs = double.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);

    switch(sign)
    {
        case "+":
            outcome = lhs + rhs;
            break;
        case "-":
            outcome = lhs - rhs;
            break;
        case "*":
            outcome = lhs * rhs;
            break;
        case "%":
            outcome = lhs % rhs;
            break;
        case "/":
            outcome = lhs / rhs;
            break;
    }

    expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + sign + rhsOperand.Text;
    result.Text = outcome.ToString();
}
```

Comment: i need to transmit different signs

Comment: what type is "sign"?

Comment: Type of sign is char

Comment: Like this? If not, please specify more what is the purpose and expected result.

Comment: private void subtractValues()
    {
        try
        {
            int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
            int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
            int outcome;
            outcome = lhs - rhs;
            expression.Text = lhsOperand.Text + "-" + rhsOperand.Text;
            result.Text = outcome.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result.Text = e.ToString();
        }

Comment: Inside of try block must stand MultiMethod but it also must do subtraction and it's not do

Comment: Check the answer now. It receives one parameter, the sign you will operate with. The outome will get the value depending of the sign you passed when you called the function.

Comment: mark as answer if it matches your request.